# Iterate javascript Object with arrays in Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, pyramid

I have a bunch of text boxes to get input from the user. When the user clicks one the "done" button(just a regular button), I get all the input and store it in an associative array and pass it to my python method.

This is what the data looks like:
[image]

then I convert it to json and send it to my python function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:6543/create_device",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("done");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //change this back to error throwing after wards
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Then in my python function I have this:

```
def create_device(request):
#get the json data from the ajax call
data = request.json_body

for key in data:
    print "key: " + key
```

This problem is I'm not sure how I'd iterate over the arrays stored under `genericData` and `staticData`. When I try to iterate them it seems only to be iterating the characters in the words instead of the arrays. This is what my javascript looks like(refer to picture to see what the data looks like):

```
    data = {
    'staticData': staticData,
    'genericData': genericData
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the code that seems to work except my array is empty and I have no idea how

```
for key in data:
    for val in data[key]:
        print "-----------------" + val
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling `JSON.stringify()` - just pass `data` directly (like, `data: data` in the `$.ajax()` call).

Comment: Check the _Python_ is working with an _Object_ and not _String_, you may have to `import json` and `data = json.loads(data)`

Comment: What framework are you using on the Python side?

Comment: sorry, I should have stated that. I'm using the pyramid framework

Comment: I added code except it seems my arrays are empty and I have no idea why, or my code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my javascript I had `genericData` and `staticData` as `= new Array()`. Instead I just did this :

```
    var genericData = {};
    var staticData = {};
```

Then kept everything else the same:

```
var data = { 'genericData' : genericData, 'staticData': staticData };
JSON.strinify(data).
```

Now my python code works as I want it to.

Comment: So you had two arrays, but was using them as "associative arrays", or "dicts", or "objects", which still worked fine because you can assign arbitrary properties to arrays in JS: `var a = []; a.foo = 'boo'`. The arrays were always empty though, so when they were passed to `JSON.stringify`, it simply serialized them as empty arrays: `[]`, because, obviously, when JSON serializer sees an array it serializes it as an array, not as object... That was an inventive way to shoot yourself in the foot indeed :))

Comment: the arrays weren't empty when I checked it in the console, when it got to the `JSON.stringify`, that's when the arrays then appeared empty, but up until that point they contained the data. I assigned them like this :`genericData[strippedName] = value`

Comment: I've expanded my comment and added it as a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

So you had two arrays, but was using them as "associative arrays", or "dicts", or "objects", which still worked fine because you can assign arbitrary properties to arrays in JS:

```
var a = []; // equivalent to a = new Array();
a.foo = 'boo';
```

The arrays were always empty though:

```
console.log(a.foo); // prints 'boo'
console.log(a['foo']); // equivalent to the above, prints 'boo'
console.log(a.length); // 0 - the array is empty
console.log(a[0]); // undefined
```

so when they were passed to JSON.stringify, it simply serialized them as empty arrays: `[]`, because, obviously, when JSON serializer sees an array it serializes it as an array, not as object...

On your screenshot you can see exactly that: you have an array of zero length, which has some additional properties assigned.

That was an inventive way to shoot yourself in the foot indeed :))

Further reading:

- [MDN article on Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [JavaScript "Associative Arrays" Considered Harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) (nicely illustrates the problem)